# How to resolve "internal table overflow" in Applescript

Tags: applescript

When attempting to load the iTunes XML/plist file, I get "internal table overflow."  After Googling, it looks like Applescript has run out of memory.  The file is 18 meg on disk, so while on the larger side of things, it should still work on a Mac with 2 gigs.

How can I resolve this?

Obviously, since it's created by iTunes, I can't control the generate of it much.

Update:  The relevant snippet:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell property list file (itunes_xml_file as string)
        tell contents
            set my_tracks to value of property list item "Tracks"
            repeat with t in items of my_tracks
```

Comment: It's hard to say what the problem is without knowing what method you're using to try loading the file. Could you post the code you're using to load the XML file?

Answer (score 2):

I guess that AppleScript is simply not made to handle this amount of data. I tried to use AppleScript a while back as well and tried to do something similar (reading an iTunes library). AppleScript's original intention was to automate applications by sending AppleEvents to them - which in combination with the weird syntax of AppleScript, confuses a lot and makes it difficult to do a lot of simple things.

After some frustrating time I decided to use Python instead, as it provides a simple module for reading the plist files: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/plistlib.html

Possibly not what you wanted to hear, but the problem with AppleScript is that it is easily overloaded with data, as the abstraction of data it works with is rather bulky and takes up lot of memory.

I'm sure if you give Python a try, you'll have something up and running in less than a hour. Python is installed on all Macs by default and is really easy to learn.

Comment: Additionally, if you need to do what AppleScript does, you can use the Python module appscript (http://appscript.sourceforge.net/) to do the same things from Python; I've not used the Python version, but I have used the Ruby version, and it's quite good.

Comment: Thanks.  If nobody can really answer how to do it this way, I'll take a look at switching to Python as Plan B.

Answer (score 1):

OS version 10.6.8

Update: **Confirmation of validity**
After initially writing the below I tried to revert the code at hand but could not reproduce the error and hid the post by "deleting" it.
Just now the error happened when loading one non-existant and one existent file-path in an options-parsing script loaded with a `load script` call, initially handled by run handler, called by the CLI osascript(1) program. This time it is revertible and I feel confident to un-"delete" it.

In short, my solution is to change `anyone_else's POSIX file path_posix` to `AppleScript's POSIX file path_posix`

**Some relation**
After writing the below I now realize that i first only saw "iTunes" and missed the relevant first line with `tell app "system events"` and the use of it's `property list file` which perhaps/actually/somehow could be related to my issue with `info for` a `POSIX file`.
A note related to OP/question: file or alias `as string` gives a colon-separated "HFS"-path. System Events handles both.

**My issue**
In a script-loading script i got `error "Internal table overflow." number -2707` from the block below.
It was issued when i called the block's handler using ~IPC~ (`app app_name's handler_name()`) (when i investigated it more thoroughly but, i had come across it before - without IPC).

```
try
    set file_modified_date to (info for my POSIX file file_path_posix)'s modification date
    true
on error error_message number error_number from error_source partial result error_result to error_class
    if {error_number} is not in {-43, -37} then error error_message number error_number from error_source partial result error_result to error_class
    false
end try
```

A (*the*(?)) parent (used for `my`) of this script, worth mentioning, is `current application` (with some levels in between) (compiled and bundled in "AppleScript Editor" to be run as a stand-alone .app)

**My solution**
Changing

```
set file_modified_date to (info for my POSIX file file_path_posix)'s modification date
```

to

```
set file_modified_date to (info for AppleScript's POSIX file file_path_posix)'s modification date
```

solved the issue - for now.

**Thoughts**
I'm guessing different ~modules~ has different "tables" (don't now much C) for handling a thing like `POSIX file` and `info for` (open "Scripting Addition" / extension (OSAX) "Standard Additions", as it (both) still is, is it not?).

Hope this helps, and that my level of detail (and parentheses) didn't loose or confuse you :) Good night.

**Diggin' 'round the cradles**
Around the AS memory grave: (Spam prevention made me downgrade all but 2 hyperlinks - give me some rep. and i'll fix it :p)
• The eminent ~has [on this error code] (http://lists.apple.com/archives/applescript-users/2005/Jul/msg00166.html) with a related but perhaps other source (and mentioning his library loader) via list.apple.com.
• Some [good questioning] (http://lists.apple.com/archives/applescript-implementors/2005/Jun/msg00104.html), some to which the below might be a slightly yawning answer:
• cs.cmu.edu provides (120625) a [pascal source from 1992](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/cmcl/link.nectar/member/airshed/psc/AFSCS/archive/mac.bin/development/languages/MPW%20Oberon%20%3ac4/OInterfaces/AppleScript.mod) that defines the same limits as my local /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OpenScripting.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AppleScript.h
• And finally a more distantly related [issue with large scripts] (http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=11760) from [macscripter.net](http://macscripter.net) - a good forum of knowledge and collection of resources around applescript.